# How to enable sending logs to rsyslog server with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, rsyslog

### Scenario

I have a rsyslog server and a client. I have a bash script with iptables rules on  both sides (client and server).The trouble is the following: if i don't run any of the bash script then it works. If i only run the server bash script it also works. But when i run both of them it doesn't work. So what i figured out is that the default DROP policy in the client is dropping the packets because it doesn't match. My doubt is why doesn't match or how the iptables should look like.

> The rsyslog is running on TCP port 514. `10.10.102.143` is the rsyslog server,`10.10.102.138` and `10.10.102.146` are the clients.

### Server bash script (the rsyslog part)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Defining the IPs and Networks
ETH0=10.10.102.
ETH1=10.10.150.
JUANMA=138
TAMARA=146
JOSE=143
EDUROAM=10.20.32.0/21
VPN=10.30.8.0/21

TEAMMATES=($JUANMA $TAMARA)
ETH0_LAN=($ETH0$JUANMA $ETH0$TAMARA)
ETH1_LAN=($ETH1$JUANMA $ETH1$TAMARA)

ALL_IPS=($EDUROAM $VPN ${ETH0_LAN[@]} ${ETH1_LAN[@]})

# Reset the configuration
iptables -F

# Drop all connectioins
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

#### RSYSLOG ####
for NETWORK in $ETH0 $ETH1
do

        for MATE in ${TEAMMATES[@]}
        do
                iptables -A INPUT -s $NETWORK$MATE -d $NETWORK$JOSE -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
        done

done
```

### Server iptables

```
root@debian:/home/lsi# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Dec  7 19:53:43 2019
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [4:244]
[0:0] -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.20.32.0/21 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[2:128] -A INPUT -s 10.30.8.0/21 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.146/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.138/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.146/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.138/32 -d 10.10.150.143/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.146/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.138/32 -d 10.10.150.143/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.146/32 -d 10.10.150.143/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[4:1212] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.146/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.138/32 -d 10.10.150.143/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.146/32 -d 10.10.150.143/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.20.32.0/21 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[1:88] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.30.8.0/21 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.102.138/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.102.146/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.150.138/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.150.146/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.102.138/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.150.143/32 -d 10.10.150.138/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.102.138/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.102.146/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.150.143/32 -d 10.10.150.138/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.150.143/32 -d 10.10.150.146/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 5555 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Dec  7 19:53:43 2019
```

### Client bash script (the rsyslog part)

```
#!/bin/bash

JOSE=10.10.102.143
TAMARA=10.10.102.146
JOSE2=10.10.150.143
TAMARA2=10.10.150.146
JUANMA=10.10.102.138


iptables -F 
iptables -X 
iptables -Z 
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP


iptables -A OUTPUT -s $JUANMA -d $JOSE -p tcp --dport 514 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

### Client iptables

```
root@debian:/home/lsi# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Dec  7 19:52:18 2019
*filter
:INPUT DROP [4:1098]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
[2321:122582] -A INPUT -j LOG
[2317:121484] -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.146/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.146/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.150.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.20.32.0/21 -d 10.10.102.138/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.30.8.0/21 -d 10.10.102.138/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.146/32 -d 10.10.102.138/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.102.138/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 10.10.102.143/32 -d 10.10.102.138/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.102.146/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[26:2344] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.150.146/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.150.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.20.32.0/21 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.30.8.0/21 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.10.102.146/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
[1:88] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
[2264:699505] -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.102.138/32 -d 10.10.102.143/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 514 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Dec  7 19:52:18 2019
```

Thanks in advance :P

Comment: @A.B thanks didn't know of that command, hope it is more readable :P

Comment: @A.B Explained which ip is from who and also used the -c argument, can you relate where the mistake may be?